# I can't get data in controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs

`$scope.items = $http.get(config.base + '/humanized/angular_data').success();`

I want to get data in `controller` and put it in `$scope.items` but I can't do that.

Comment: Ajax calls are asynchronous. It won't assign the data until the call returns. Also, need to see more to help.

Comment: you need to return a promise, and then get your data when that promise has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In older versions of angular you were able to directly assign promises to `$scope`, which would manage the resolve process. This has been turned off in the current version, with a complete removal planned. To perform what you need, `$scope.items` should be assigned inside a resolved callback (eg: `.success(function(results){ /* assign here */})`)